# Convert mins:secs:milliseconds to proper time in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have an excel with such format:

[image]

[image]

I'm trying to get the 12.07.41am in python (I need to do all edits in python)

```
from datetime import timedelta, date, datetime
df['start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start'])
df['start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start'], format = '%y/%m/%d #H:%M:%S')
```

but is giving me error: hour must be in 0..23

Answer (score 0):

Given a df of the form:

```
import pandas as pd
tin = [['07:04.2', '08:12.6'], ['12:14.2', "13:12.8"], ['07:24.0', '07:36.6'], ['09:14.2', "10:12.8"]] 
df=pd.DataFrame(data=tin, columns=["start", 'end'])
```

which creates the df:

```
    start   end
0   07:04.2 08:12.6
1   12:14.2 13:12.8
2   07:24.0 07:36.6
3   09:14.2 10:12.8
```

You can convert the time data in start and end columns to datetime objects using:

```
df['start'] = [pd.to_datetime(t[0:t.index('.')] + f":{int(float(t[t.index('.'):])*60)}", format='%H:%M:%S') for t in df['start'].to_list()]
df['end'] = [pd.to_datetime(t[0:t.index('.')] + f":{int(float(t[t.index('.'):])*60)}", format='%H:%M:%S') for t in df['end'].to_list()]
```

Producing an updated df:

```
    start               end
0   1900-01-01 07:04:12 1900-01-01 08:12:36
1   1900-01-01 12:14:12 1900-01-01 13:12:48
2   1900-01-01 07:24:00 1900-01-01 07:36:36
3   1900-01-01 09:14:12 1900-01-01 10:12:48
1
​
```